# Retaining selected values for drop down link in jsp/servelts

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to populate the number of drop down lists depending upon the data in the database, for e.g if I have 6 records, I will generate 6 dropdown lists. Please specify how to retain the values in the drop down lists after submit.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList,java.util.List" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Course Learning Objectives to Student Outcomes Mapper</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Course Learning Objectives to Student Outcomes Mapper</h1>

<c:choose>

<c:when test="${empty id}">

<form method="get" action="CLOtoSO">

<select name="id">
<c:forEach items="${CourseIdMap}" var="Course">
    <option value="${Course.value}">${Course.key}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>
</c:when>

<c:otherwise>

<table border="1">
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
<c:forEach items="${SOIdsMap}" var="SOId">
<td title="${SODescriptionsMap[SOId.value]}">${SOId.key}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${CLODescriptionsMap}" var="CLODescription">
<tr>
<td>${CLODescription.value}</td>
<c:forEach items="${SOIdsMap}" var="SOId">
  <td><select form="CLOtoSOform" name="map-${SOId.value}_${CLODescription.key}">
  
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="R">R</option>
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  </select></td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<form method="post" action="CLOtoSO" id="CLOtoSOform">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}">
  <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean selected values in dropdown after submit the form?

Comment: yes @VinothKrishnan

Comment: i want selected values in second drop down list i.e map-${SOId.value}_${CLODescription.key} to be retained after submission

Comment: You can use the same code, use soldId instead.

Comment: can u please suggest me by just using the servlets

Comment: I've updated by the java code.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the data (selected drop down values) to servlet, you can send it back to the JSP as well.

I'm giving sample for one drop down,

```
request.setAttribute("selectedId", request.getParameter("id"));
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/mypage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);

request.getAttribute("selectedId")
```

And in your JSP page check your `request.getAttribute("selectedId")` is true. 
If so do the following,

```
<c:forEach items="${SOIdsMap}" var="SOId">
    <select form="CLOtoSOform" name="map-${SOId.value}_${CLODescription.key}">
        <option value="${SOId.key}" ${SOId.key == selectedId ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${SOId.value}</option>
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps you.